# Updating Divs when observable collection changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, observablecollection

Is there any plugin or jquery utility that will update my list of divs bound to an observable collection when items get added/removed to that collection? We have 1000s of items and so are looking for the most optimal way to add/remove divs when the bound list changes.

We would be interested in hearing about this in KO or jquery.tmpl.

Comment: What do you want it to do that KO doesn't already do?

Comment: I'd accept some more answers to your previous questions before posting more... it will greatly increase the chance of having this answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe not the answer that your looking for, but it could be one way to do it.
I would wrap the array within an object that has an Add and Remove method(or other function that change the array)

```
var Collection = (function () {
    var collectionArray = new Array();
    //"private" methods
    function updatePageDivs()
    {
        //Logic to update your Divs
    }
    //"public" methods
    return{
        Add: function(element){
            collectionArray[collectionArray.length] = element;
             updatePageDivs();
        },
        Remove: function(element){
            //other logic to remove elements and to trigger the updatePage
        }
    }

});
```

You can now call

```
Collection.Add()
```

and

```
Collection.Remove()
```

to change your javascript collection. Both will update your pagedivs.